# spring websockets using stomp and sockjs create new connection on opening new tab

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I am using spring websockets using stomp and sockjs without spring security . When I have one my app in a browser, then new socket connection established, but when I open another tab in same browser, it also create new socket connection.So i want to stop this behaviour and want it to use the same connection id to on opening new tab.Its a chat app.Using code from this blog:

https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat

can anyone give me working code how to store connection in localstorage n retrieve the stored socket connection in new tab from localstorage?

```
            function connect() {
            var socket = new SockJS('/spring-mvc-java/chat');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);  
            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {

                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function(messageOutput) {
                    showMessageOutput(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: You will need to store that connection ID so that it can be shared across tabs. `LocalStorage` is the simplest solution for it.

Comment: can u please provide me any example link?

Comment: Ok suppose you have connection id `id_1` then you can store it in LocalStorage using using `localStorage.setItem('conId', 'id_1')`, to to get this id in another tab, you can use `localStorage.getItem('conId')`. Using this id you will have to open new WebSocket connection in the tab using this saved connection ID.

Comment: ok thanks and connection id id_1 u refer here is websocket session id of user?

Comment: Whatever you're using to identify different sessions, it could be a request parameter, just a path variable or header.

Comment: ok thanks for response

Comment: i cant get it Using this id you will have to open new WebSocket connection in the tab using this saved connection ID.

Comment: i m using simplebroker n it gives me random  websocket id

Comment: i am confused how to open new connection using this id localStorage.getItem('conId')?

Answer (score 0):

Local storage in window is the simplest solution to above problem. Store the session id in local storage object and you can access across other tabs.Retrieve the session id from the object and reuse for the connection.

Example:

> ```
> localStorage.setItem('sessionId', '123abc');
> ```

Retrieve the same object in other tab with:

> ```
> localStorage.getItem("sessionId");
> ```

You can refer to below link on how to use localStorage:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: can u provide me code please using socket connection

Comment: i m already using that code , http://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring i dont c any localstorage thing in that example

Comment: function connect() {
                var socket = new SockJS('/spring-mvc-java/chat');
                stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);  
                stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                    setConnected(true);
                    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function(messageOutput) {
                        showMessageOutput(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
                    });
                });
            }